# Por que algumas fontes listam o vocábulo "miríade" como coletivo para insetos?

Tags: etimologia, número-gramatical, substantivos

Eu sou um cientista entomologista. Apenas recentemente, estudando a gramática portuguesa novamente, que descobri este fato, que não consigo entender.

Encontrei a definição primeiramente na *Nova Gramática da Língua Portuguesa para Concursos*, por Rodrigo Bezerra, 6.ª Ed. Editora Método, pag. 147 (vide na foto). Esta palavra encontra-se em uma tabela listando termos coletivos que se extende entre as pags. 145-148, apresentada com o seguinte enunciado.

> Coletivos: São os substantivos que, no singular, indicam uma coleção, um agrupamento, um conjunto de seres da mesma espécie. **Observe abaixo uma tabela com os principais coletivos**:

O livro também pode ser encontrado no seguinte [sítio](https://forumdeconcursos.com/wp-content/uploads/wpforo/attachments/2/1581-Nova-gramtica-da-lngua-portuguesa-para-concursos-Rodrigo-Bezerra--7-ed-2015.pdf). 
Adicionalmente, pela internet existem alguns [sites](https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/2283718) (informais) onde o mesmo termo foi assim definido.

[image]

Por favor, alguém saberia se esta definição é realmente oficial e qual teria sido sua origem?

Comment: Vem do grego: https://dicionario.priberam.org/miriade um grande número de algo. Será então que só quer dizer (como em espanhol) um grande número?

Comment: @Lambie -- Estou intrigado com a relação oficial com os insetos.

Comment: Eu acredito o que você disse. Francamente? ***Eu acho que ele não tem razão. Imagino que você teria sabido o termo, dado o seu campo***. Não é o campo do Bezerra.

Comment: Depois de pensar um pouco, acho que a página está dando exemplos de substantivos. Claro, é possível dizer uma miríada (o palavra sem jeito :)) de insetos mas isto não implica que seja um termo formal para coletivo. Simplesmente um monte de insetos.  Pode haver uma miríada de qualquer tipo de animal, pessoa, lugar, acontecimento, etc. Talvez eu deveria colocar uma resposta.....miríada rima com lusíada (de Luso ou luso). E são da mesma banda. :) [literários]

Comment: @Lambie O termo aparece listado numa tabela de *coletivos* que se extende dentre as pags. 145-148.

Comment: Já pesquisei e tenho a resposta. O livro lista os principais coletivos, só que as palavras depois do **de** podem ser muito mais variadas do que se vê. Ele deveria ter posto: miríada de insetos, **etc.**. São poucos os termos limitativos em relação ao segundo verbete. Uma miríada seria uma delas. Mais tarde colocarei uma resposta formal.

Comment: Sim, Lambie, tans razão. Uma miríade são 10000; não é um substantivo coletivo, da mesma forma que dezena ou milhão. E não é exclusivo do português: en inglês *myriad* é metafórico, mas em japonês [万](http://www.nihongoresources.com/dictionaries/universal.html?type=kanji&query=%E4%B8%87) ("man") é literal (há notas de "1man¥=1*10k¥", e não de "10sen¥ = 10*1000¥").

Comment: @Lambie, também concordo que *miríade* não é especificamente insetos. Mas tu afinal respondes ou não? Se não te despachas, respondo eu!

Comment: @ANeves, isso de não ser substantivo coletivo é mais complicado; eu também tenderia a não pensar em *monte* (de batatas, trapos, chatices) como substantivo coletivo, mas parece que é.

Comment: Por favor atentem para o núcleo da pergunta. A tabela apresenta o vocábulo como Coletivo específico (i.e. *todos* vocábulos apresentados se seguem de “de”, por páginas a fio). É uma referência gramatical, e realmente me pareceu bizarro e possivelmente um erro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Significado e Uso

Os doze dicionários¹ dos últimos trezentos anos que consultei concordam: ***miríade*** significa apenas **‘dez mil’** ou **‘número muito elevado’**; só por si, *miríade* não significa ‘quantidade de insetos’ ou de qualquer outra coisa em particular. Os exemplos da literatura no Google Books, abundantes nos últimos dois séculos, confirmam: encontramos muitos *miríade de insetos, de estrelas, de anjos, de cores, de estilos*, de tudo o que se queira; mas *miríade* sem dizer de quê, não se encontra.

A aceção ‘dez mil’ só se encontra em obras antigas: excluindo edições e citações posteriores dessas obras, o último exemplo que encontrei é de 1622; a partir daí só encontrei a aceção ‘número muito elevado’. Isto assemelha-se à situação no inglês. Diz o [Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/myriad#etymonline_v_45211) que (tradução minha) “o uso especificamente numérico encontra-se habitualmente em traduções do grego ou latim”, línguas em que a palavra era realmente usada no sentido ‘dez mil’.

### Classificação: substantivo coletivo ou o quê?

*Miríade* tem de facto cabimento entre os substantivos coletivos. Há coletivos de dois tipos: os **dependentes**, como *pilha*, que precisam de um complemento, como *de pratos, de livros, de caixas*, etc.; e os **autónomos**, como *maquinaria*, que não admitem complemento, ou como *matilha* que admite um complemento opcional e redundante—podemos dizer só *matilha* ou *matilha de cães*. *Miríade* pertence ao dependentes. Quando pensamos em substantivos coletivos, creio que são os autónomos que mais facilmente nos vêm à cabeça. De modo que para os dependentes eu vou apelar à autoridade da *Gramática do Português* (Gulbenkian, Lisboa, 2013, tomo I, p. 973-4):

> Em contrapartida, os nomes coletivos que não representam lexicalmente o tipo de entidades que formam o grupo chamam-se **coletivos dependentes** ou **agrupadores** […] são exemplos *braçada, conjunto, grupo* e *montão*.
>
> Estes nomes coletivos necessitam de ser complementados por uma expressão adicional que introduza informação sobre a composição do grupo […] cf. *braçada* {*de flores/de lenha*}, *conjunto* {*de regras/de países*}, *grupo* {*de deputados/de rapazes*}, *montão* {*de pedras/de destroços*}. Nestes casos, é a combinação do nome com o sintagma preposicional que forma uma expressão coletiva semanticamente completa, equivalente a um nome coletivo autónomo.

Estes nomes coletivos dependentes não são inteiramente pacíficos. A *Gramática do Português* explica (p, 974) que:

> Por não serem semanticamente completos, algumas gramáticas excluem inteiramente da classe dos coletivos os nomes aqui tratados como coletivos dependentes (ver, p.e., Bosque 1999), argumentando que se trata, na realidade, de quantificadores lexicais indefinidos do tipo de *alguns, muitos, vários*, etc.

Nesta perspetiva, *miríade* seria um quantificador lexical indefinido, por *miríade de insetos* ser mais ou menos o mesmo que *muitíssimos insetos*.

A minha primeira reação foi, como o ANeves acima, considerar *miríade* um numeral coletivo, como *dúzia, milhar, milhão*, usado muito vagamente. O problema é que na linguagem corrente *miríade* significa apenas *numero muito elevado*; o sentido *dez mil* aparece apenas em obras antigas ou comentários sobre essas obras. Deve ser por isto que encontrei *miríade* em várias listas de substantivos coletivos, mas não de numerais coletivos.

### Nota sobre a tabela

Posto isto, a tabela é no mínimo confusa e induz facilmente em erro, porque não deixa claro como é que o conteúdo da coluna da direita deve ser interpretado. O leitor poderia pensar que *de insetos* está para *miríade* tal como, logo na linha acima, *de cães* está para *matilha*, isto é que que *miríade* só por si pudesse significar ‘conjunto de insetos’ tal como *matilha* significa ‘conjunto de cães’. Tanto mais que logo poucas linhas acima houve o cuidado de juntar um *etc.* para indicar que *de bois* e *de elefantes* são apenas dois dos complementos possíveis de *manada* (e o mesmo com *nuvem* umas linhas abaixo), coisa que não foi feita com o *de insetos* da *miríade*.

### Etimologia

A palavra vem do grego *myrias*, *myriados* no genitivo, que já significava ‘dez mil’ ou ´número incontável’; passou ao latim tardio, *myriadis* no genitivo; aparece em francês como *myriade* na aceção ‘dez mil’ em 1525 e ‘número infinito’ em 1557 (ver [CNTRL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/myriade)); e em inglês como *myriad* em 1550-60 ([Etymoline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/myriad#etymonline_v_45211)).

Em português encontrei [*myriada* em 1597](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dl5JAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP871&dq=myriada&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiixriuv9TiAhUkUt8KHSJnAXcQ6AEIVzAG#v=onepage&q=myriada&f=false)² e [*meriada* em 1622](https://books.google.pt/books?id=v6YRrJll5HAC&pg=PA311&dq=meriadas&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq2ZKcgNjiAhWaBWMBHR5mBYcQ6AEIQDAD#v=onepage&q=meriadas&f=false).³ Estas são os únicos exemplos que encontrei no sentido ‘dez mil’ (tirando citações posteriores destas obras). A palavra vem no [*Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino* Raphael Bluteau (1728)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=wFd6AvENzikC&pg=PA65&dq=%22myriada%20He%20tomado%20do%20Grego%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNsNCR3NLiAhVD2-AKHXygBZMQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22myriada%20He%20tomado%20do%20Grego%22&f=false) que dá apenas a aceção ‘dez mil’; o [dicionário de Moraes Silva de 1789] faz o mesmo, mas a [4ª edição, de 1831](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lwxaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA346&lpg=PA346&dq=%22Miriadas%20infindas%20de%20Serafins%20cerc%C3%A3o%20seu%20trono%22&source=bl&ots=Rgv8COqMCE&sig=ACfU3U3td4xiKIvtd1IFCR4MWhfgafxTwg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxj56Imd3iAhUwxIUKHQT-C8oQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Miriadas%20infindas%20de%20Serafins%20cerc%C3%A3o%20seu%20trono%22&f=false), já acrescenta o significado figurado ‘grande multidão’, dando como exemplo “*Miriadas* infindas de Serafins cercão seu trono”. O [dicionário de Domingos Vierira de 1873](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WhZnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA373&dq=%22quantidade%20indefinida%20e%20innumeravel%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDv5mmlt3iAhUAAWMBHRe3A6cQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22quantidade%20indefinida%20e%20innumeravel%22&f=false) dá a aceção ‘dez mil’ como “Termo de Antiguidade” e diz que na “linguagem ordinária” (isto é, ‘linguagem comum’; *ordinário* naqueles tempos não significava ‘reles, mau’; era só o oposto de extraordinário), significa “quantidade indefinida e innumeravel”, o que pelo que eu vi no Google Books reflete tanto o uso no século XIX como o atual.

---

**Notas**:
¹ Doze dicionários (19 edições): [Raphael Bluteau (1728)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=wFd6AvENzikC&pg=PA65&dq=%22myriada%20He%20tomado%20do%20Grego%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNsNCR3NLiAhVD2-AKHXygBZMQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22myriada%20He%20tomado%20do%20Grego%22&f=false), Morais Silva ([1789](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kPBDAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA107&dq=%22myriada%20f%20f%20numeral%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi92IfKrN7iAhWoQxUIHeFYCW0Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22myriada%20f%20f%20numeral%22&f=false), 1813, 1823, [1831](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WhZnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA373&dq=%22quantidade%20indefinida%20e%20innumeravel%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDv5mmlt3iAhUAAWMBHRe3A6cQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22quantidade%20indefinida%20e%20innumeravel%22&f=false), 1858, 1877), [Domingos Vieira (1873)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kPBDAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA107&dq=%22myriada%20f%20f%20numeral%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi92IfKrN7iAhWoQxUIHeFYCW0Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22myriada%20f%20f%20numeral%22&f=false), Cândido de Figueiredo (1899, 1913, 1939), Sociedade de Língua Portuguesa (1958-71), Lello Universal (1992), Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001), Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) e dicionários online, [Priberam](http://Lisboa%20(2001),%20Houaiss%20(Lisboa,%202002)%20e%20dicion%C3%A1rios%20online,%20[Priberam,%20[Infop%C3%A9dia,%20[Aulete,%20[Michaellis), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/mir%C3%ADade), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/mir%C3%ADade), Michaellis.
² “[D]igamos com Nicephoro Calixto, que em todo o Imperio Romano, se contarão nesta discripção vinte & seis mil, & trinta & **sete Myriadas, & vallendo cada Myriada dez mil**, vem a somar duzentos & sessenta contos, & trezentas & settenta mil pessoas.” [Frei Bernardo de Brito, *Monarchia Lusitana*, 1ª parte, Alcobaça, 1597, p. 415.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dl5JAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP871&dq=myriada&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiixriuv9TiAhUkUt8KHSJnAXcQ6AEIVzAG#v=onepage&q=myriada&f=false)
³ “[O] Ceo empireo tem de comprimento **dez mil, trezentas, quatorze meriadas**, oitocẽtos, cincomil, setenta, & dez milhares de passos, & em largura tres mil, seis centas meriadas.” [Padre frey Antonio Rozado, *Tratados sobre os quatro novíssimos conlugares comuns*, Porto, 1622, p. 311.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=v6YRrJll5HAC&pg=PA311&dq=meriadas&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq2ZKcgNjiAhWaBWMBHR5mBYcQ6AEIQDAD#v=onepage&q=meriadas&f=false)

Comment: um miríada de [algo] e paralelo a um monte de algo, semanticamente e não um numeral coletivo. um número muito elevado agrupado ou em um grupo. O verbete existe em inglês como adjetivo e substantivo. Em francês e espanhol, é só substantivo. O uso da palavra tanto em francês e em inglês é corrente em boas redações. Nunca foi usado para referir-se a 10,000 de algo nos tempos modernos.

Comment: @Lambie, então estamos basicamente de acordo, não?

Comment: Claro. Me irrita quando as pessoas que fazem perguntas não queiram reconhecer que não se deram conta de algo. Tudo bem. Acontece comigo TODO santo día. Tudo dependia de entender esse aspeto que você encontrou/sublinhou sobre dependentes e agrupadores. Agrupem-se gente. :) Credo. (Ainde lhe devo uma resposta sobre o círculo vicioso mas estou sufocando baixo o peso de uma tradução em informática que nem o diabo entenderia). Paciência.

Comment: @Lambie, eu compreendo o Scientist: a tabela (a menos que haja alguma explicação intridutória) induz facilmente em erro; eles escreveram "etc" em  "manada - de bois, de elefantes, etc", dando a entender que "bois, elefantes" não é exaustivo (o mesmo com "nuvem - de mosquitos, de gafanhotos, etc."), mas não o fizeram com *miríade*. Compreende-se que uma pessoa pensasse que o autor queria dizer que *miríade* por si só significava uma porção de insetos. Eu ainda pesquisei um bocado para me certificar que não era esse o caso (mesmo sabendo que se podia dizer *miríade* de qualquer coisa).

Comment: Jacinto: eu disse isso lá em cima. Eles deveriam de ter escrito por exemplo. Foi meu segundo comentário.

Comment: @Scientist, feito.

Comment: Perfeito! Estou tentando entrar em contato com o autor para comunicar-lhe o problema... Parece que persiste ao longo das edições e acho que a confusão pode ter permeado pelos websites !

Comment: "Myriad" é bastante usado nas ilhas Britânicas para designar "vários", "diversos", "muitos" ou qualquer coisa difícil ou impossível de contar ou que não valha a pena contar. A etimologia é a mesma, imagino que o significado seja similar.